# Email automatico en Android con Javamail

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentando que mi app envíe automaticamente un email, sin que el usuario deba interaccionar. No me da problemas al compilar, sino que cuando la pruebo en un teléfono real, en el momento que llega a esa parte del código la aplicación se bloquea y se cierra.
¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo? Dejo el código que estoy usando...

CLASE ENVIAR MENSAJE:

```
package com.android.mdw.demo;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class EnviarEmail {
    public static String emailEnvio = "XXX@gmail.com";
    public static String passwordEmailEnvio = "@XXX";

    public void EnviarEmail(String Mensaje, String Asunto, String email) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(emailEnvio, passwordEmailEnvio);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailEnvio));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(email));
            message.setSubject(Asunto);
            message.setText(Mensaje);

            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.w("ERROR", "No se ha podido enviar el email de confirmación.");
        }
    }
}
```

CLASE EMAIL AVISO

```
package com.android.mdw.demo;

public class EmailAviso {
    public void EmailAviso ()  {
        String Mensaje = "CUERPO";
        String Asunto = "ASUNTO";
        String email = "AQUIENVA@gmail.com";

        EnviarEmail EnviarEmail = new EnviarEmail();
        EnviarEmail.EnviarEmail(Mensaje, Asunto, email);

    }
}
```

RESUMEN CLASE MAIN (LLAMA AL METODO PARA ENVIAR EL CORREO)

```
boolean PRUEBA=true;
boolean PRUEBA1=true;

if(PRUEBA==true && PRUEBA1==true) {
EmailAviso EmailAviso = new EmailAviso();
EmailAviso.EmailAviso();
}
```

LOG:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.android.mdw.demo, PID: 18001
>       android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>           at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:816)
>           at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
>           at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
>           at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
>           at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
>           at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
>           at com.android.mdw.demo.EnviarEmail.EnviarEmail(EnviarEmail.java:41)
>           at com.android.mdw.demo.EmailAviso.EmailAviso(EmailAviso.java:10)
>           at com.android.mdw.demo.Main.onSensorChanged(Main.java:77)
>           at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:699)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Prueba a usar threads

Comment: ¿No te da ningún error? ¿has probado a depurar el código o mirar el log?

Comment: @PabloLozano he dejado el log que me da, a ver si puedes ver ahi algo...

Comment: Dale a [edit] y añade el log del error completo ahí (en la pregunta)

Comment: @PabloLozano cambiado, gracias

Comment: Como te ha comentado @JDev, el error NetworkOnMainThreadException (Que traducido sería (Excepción: Uso de la red en el hilo principal), lo solucionarás usando otro hilo para mandar el correo.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme como hacerlo? No se trabajar con hilos...